# Exception handling in StreamingResponseBody not working

Tags: java, spring, outputstream

I'm trying to catch an exception thrown in my implementation of `StreamingResponseBody`, I can see the exception being thrown inside the class however the thrown exception my handling seems to work, But I am not able to get my custom message and my response code is `200`.

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = "application/json")
public StreamingResponseBody test(@RequestParam(value = "var1") final String test) throws IOException{
    return new StreamingResponseBody() {
        @Override
        public void writeTo(final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException{
            try {
                // Some operations..
            } catch (Exception MyExceptione e) {
                throw new MyException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}

@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleMyException(MyException exception) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(exception.getHttpStatus()).body(
            ErrorDTO.builder()
                    .message(exception.getMessage())
                    .description(exception.getHttpStatus().getReasonPhrase())
                    .build());
}
```

I would expect my `ControllerAdvice` to return an `ResponseEntity` with a `Http Status` of 500.

Comment: The `StreamingResponseBody` is handled async, and it is streaming, so the first part of the response is written quite early on, afterwards the content is actually being streamed. As the first part is already send, it cannot handle the exception.

Comment: you cannot return ResponseEntity (which becomes full http response) because you have already pushed header of the response into the output stream (and probably you did send it over the network already) so its too late to change content of that response. StreamingResponseBody is "handled" when response body is beeing written into the output stream (buffered to some extent) after response headers are written. To overcome this you would have to buffer whole response - but that invalidates the purpose of streaming response body.

Comment: Is there any to change HttpStatus Code on exception?